# Woocommerce shipping zone in the same country (UK) is not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

[image: Woocommerce Shipping Method]

I tried using 3 zone of UK country, but if do search a specific postcode, it only shows the **Mainland UK** shipping method.

Example if I search a postcode near in **Northern Ireland**, I expected to see **Standard Delivery** shipping method only but **Mainland UK** shipping method is showing as always.

I'm missing something in the setup? or I setup it wrong?

Thanks guys ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag Mainland UK as your last zone (before rest of the world).